# Accidentally deleted Windows partitions when installing Ubuntu 18.04, then tried to recover using TestDisk

Tags: system-installation, data-recovery

I installed Ubuntu 18.04.4 on a laptop that had windows 10 on it. While installing I selected the default option of cleaning the drive. I thought it would clear just the system 'drive' (C 'drive' on Windows), but it cleared the whole hard drive. I had some important data on it. So how shall I proceed to recover it?

I followed some articles, specifically [this one](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step).

I used TestDisk on Ubuntu, but I got stuck at the very end.

Following the above tutorial, I followed the steps as above mentioned.

Then at the step to find the deleted partitions I performed a *Deeper search*. It took about 2½ hrs to check the whole hard drive out for partitions. (I had to perform this thrice since on clicking *enter* accidentally it went to the previous menu).

When I finally found the deleted partitions, I changed the partition type to L (Logical) from D (Deleted). I was unsure of which deleted ones to choose initially, but then I checked the part of storage they occupy. E made the guesses as follows:

This image shows the deleted partitions entry and my selections to which seemed the drivers that I required.

[image: hen]

Then it showed me this error and on clicking *enter* it took me to previous menu.

[This is the message I received and I am not sure how to proceed ahead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StvqB.jpg)

How shall I proceed ahead? And is there a way to get around that whole 2½ hours of searching again as i have the log file of previous TestDisk session. Can that help?

Comment: Classic Windows-based misunderstanding. Sorry for your frustration. Outside of Windows, a *drive* is the physical (spinning-disk) hardware, with multiple *partitions* upon it. In Windows (only), every partition is confusingly called a "drive" for some reason.

Comment: Did you go through the [TestDisk tutorial](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step)? It answers your questions and saves you a lot of mistakes.

Comment: @user535733 thank you for the clarification on drives and partitions. And Yes i went through the tutorial, but i am unsure which partitions to turn into L(logical) and on selecting the partitions as shown in the image, it gave me the prompt saying **invalid partition structure**. I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Why do you suppose are there so many duplicate partitions in your screenshot?  Why are you changing partitions *to* deleted status? Every action you perform using that hard drive, you risk making the problem worse. If the data is valuable, it's better that you pay some data recovery service than hack away at this without being sure you're not making the matter worse.  Hindsight is 20/20, but truly important/valuable data has got to be stored in *at least* two different places